# The remote script failed with exit code 100 in octopus

Tags: octopus-deploy

Deploying package 'C:\Octopus\Files\WebACE.1.0.802-WebAceReleaseBuild-20253.nupkg-9ff55845-580c-472e-be35-13f289216dd3' to machine 'https://172.16.112.175:10933/'

```
March 5th 2019 12:01:39Info
Deploying package:    C:\Octopus\Files\WebACE.1.0.802-WebAceReleaseBuild-20253.nupkg-9ff55845-580c-472e-be35-13f289216dd3
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Octopus\Applications\Dev15\Development\WebACE\1.0.802-WebAceReleaseBuild-20253\PrecompiledWeb\localhost_2141\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.3.0\runtimes\unix\lib\netstandard1.1\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll'.
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
   at SharpCompress.Readers.IReaderExtensions.WriteEntryToFile(IReader reader, String destinationFileName, ExtractionOptions options)
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
   at Calamari.Integration.Packages.NuGet.NupkgExtractor.Extract(String packageFile, String directory, Boolean suppressNestedScriptWarning) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\14ffc968155e4956\source\Calamari\Integration\Packages\NuGet\NupkgExtractor.cs:line 57
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
   at Calamari.Deployment.Conventions.ExtractPackageConvention.Install(RunningDeployment deployment) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\14ffc968155e4956\source\Calamari\Deployment\Conventions\ExtractPackageConvention.cs:line 31
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
   at Calamari.Deployment.ConventionProcessor.RunInstallConventions() in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\14ffc968155e4956\source\Calamari\Deployment\ConventionProcessor.cs:line 60
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
   at Calamari.Deployment.ConventionProcessor.RunConventions() in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\14ffc968155e4956\source\Calamari\Deployment\ConventionProcessor.cs:line 28
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
Running rollback conventions...
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
Value cannot be null.
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
Parameter name: path
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
System.ArgumentNullException
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo..ctor(String path)
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
   at Calamari.Integration.FileSystem.CalamariPhysicalFileSystem.EnumerateFiles(String parentDirectoryPath, String[] searchPatterns) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\14ffc968155e4956\source\Calamari\Integration\FileSystem\CalamariPhysicalFileSystem.cs:line 194
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
   at Calamari.Integration.Scripting.PackagedScriptRunner.FindScripts(RunningDeployment deployment) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\14ffc968155e4956\source\Calamari\Integration\Scripting\PackagedScriptRunner.cs:line 62
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
   at Calamari.Integration.Scripting.PackagedScriptRunner.RunScripts(RunningDeployment deployment) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\14ffc968155e4956\source\Calamari\Integration\Scripting\PackagedScriptRunner.cs:line 30
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
   at Calamari.Deployment.ConventionProcessor.RunRollbackConventions() in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\14ffc968155e4956\source\Calamari\Deployment\ConventionProcessor.cs:line 69
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
   at Calamari.Deployment.ConventionProcessor.RunConventions() in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\14ffc968155e4956\source\Calamari\Deployment\ConventionProcessor.cs:line 48
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
   at Calamari.Commands.DeployPackageCommand.Execute(String[] commandLineArguments) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\14ffc968155e4956\source\Calamari\Commands\DeployPackageCommand.cs:line 117
March 5th 2019 12:02:10Error
   at Calamari.Program.Execute(String[] args) in Z:\buildAgent\workDir\14ffc968155e4956\source\Calamari\Program.cs:line 45
March 5th 2019 12:02:15Fatal
The remote script failed with exit code 100
```

Comment: Getting this on only specific deployments when i use Feature builds or develop builds everything works as expected this only happens on release builds

Comment: FYI i already checked all permissions and such and other builds work perfectly fine to the same folder etc..

Comment: Did you ever figure out the cause of this?  Am running into this now and not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

The length of the path in the error message is too long. It is 263 characters.

`C:\Octopus\Applications\Dev15\Development\WebACE\1.0.802-WebAceReleaseBuild-20253\PrecompiledWeb\localhost_2141\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.3.0\runtimes\unix\lib\netstandard1.1\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll`

If you say you are only getting it on `Feature` builds, then it may be caused by the branch name and build number is in the package name. 
You could also consider what other binaries you are shipping in the package and if they can be removed.